# iOS SceneKit: XCode "breaks" imported DAE material colors

Tags: ios, xcode, scenekit, arkit, collada

First of all, I apologize if for the non-technical language regarding 3D design, it's out of my scope.
I'm using some DAE files for displaying 3D models on SceneKit, provided by a 3D designer. However when I add it to the `scnassets` folder on XCode, all material colors get "corrupted". Take for example this DAE for a jewel, the blue and white version is visualized on an online viewer and is the correct one. The other black and white is a screenshot I took from my phone running an ARSession with the dae loaded on a node.

[image: Correct colors]
[image: Wrong colors]

Any idea on how I can preserve the original colors?

**Update** Running from the command line I get lots of this warnings:

> $ xcrun scntool --convert ARO-E-BLING.DAE --output cliConverted.scn --format scn
>
> Warning: The instance_effect with URL file:/Users/Leandro/Documents/ARO-E-BLING.DAE#White stone-fx does not reference an effect, skipping it
>
> Warning: The instance_effect with URL file:/Users/Leandro/Documents/ARO-E-BLING.DAE#Blue Stone-fx does not reference an effect, skipping it
>
> Warning: Found an invalid material [White], reverting to a default material
>
> Warning: Found an invalid material [Blue], reverting to a default material

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, running it from the command line helped me find the solution. It seems `scntool` fails if materials and/or effects in the dae have whitespaces on it. For instance I had things like:

```
<material id="Blue Stone" name="Blue Stone">
  <instance_effect url="#Blue Stone-fx"/>
</material>
```

which I had to replace for

```
<material id="Blue_Stone" name="Blue_Stone">
  <instance_effect url="#Blue_Stone-fx"/>
</material>
```

**UPDATE Jan 8 2018** I submitted a bug report to Apple and they stated that this behavior is not a bug stating that:

> According to the Collada spec
>   (https://www.khronos.org/files/collada_spec_1_4.pdf) the URL of an
>   "instance_effect" is of type "xs:anyURI".
>
> URIs are not allowed to contain space, they must be escaped ("Spaces
>   should instead be escaped using %20" in
>   http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_anyURI.html).

Comment: Great answer. I do not know enough to be sure but this looks like a bug. You should log it with Apple: bugreport.apple.com

Comment: @RoboticCat did that, they dismissed it as not being a bug (see answer update if interested)

Comment: Thanks for the update. So not a bug after all; that makes this a very useful answer.